# can I connect to MySQL on a GCP CE VM instance from Windows MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench

As the title implies, I'm looking to connect from my windows laptop, to a GCP VM instance, in which mysql is running there.  The database works fine, and if I go into an ssh client from their cloud connection, I can directly use mysql client and interrogate the DB.

I would like to use my local windows MySQL Workbench app, and be able to perform queries, just like I did in my localhost version I built before porting it up to GCP.

How to do this, (without subscribing to GCP Cloud SQL) and attach to my VM instance's sql?

///////////////////////////////////////////////
from John's comment, here's my net stat output:

```
netstat -tlnp | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17007/mysqld
```

and the 3306 is indeed in the port list in mysql:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

so my conclusion is that I need to open the port?

@john:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1669/mysqld   

NAME         NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW     DENY  DISABLED
mysqlaccess  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:3306        False
```

Telnet test of the port from my laptop:

```
C:\Users\fumanchu>telnet x.x.x.x 3306
[                                                                                                                        5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1zzzzzzzz}<[:X'mysql_native_password

Connection to host lost.
```

attempt to use GUI from MySQL Workbench:

ADDED console GCP log showing my VPC entry is there:

```
mysqlaccess
Ingress
Apply to all    
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:3306
Allow
1000
Off —   —
```

Comment: The first step is to determine the MySQL is set up for connections. Run this command and put the output in your question: `netstat -tlnp | grep 3306`. If nothing appears, log in to MySQL and run this command: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` and then try again replacing `3306` with the correct port number. MySQL might be configured to listen only for connections to localhost or from all interfaces. You need the local listening address to be similar to `0.0.0.0:3306`. Then configure out VPC firewall rule allowing external connections from your IP address.

Comment: MySQL is listening on localhost (127.0.0.1). You must configure `my.cnf` to listen on all interfaces. Open my.cnf and find the `bind-address` line. Change to `0.0.0.0`. Restart MySQL and repeat the command `netstat -tlnp | grep 3306` to verify the local listening address is `0.0.0.0:3306`. Then create a VPC firewall rule. Restarting MySQL is OS specific. For recent versions of Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS `systemctl restart mysqld`. For some systems `service mysqld restart`.

Comment: @JohnHanley, so I'm chipping away at it...I have done what you said and indeed the netstat reflects the 0.0.0.0 now.  I have a VPC firewall setup as well.  updated in the edit of the post.  what remains is the connection to the GCP VM from windows MySQL Workbench, which seems to still not like connecting.

Comment: To connect from Workbench, you need the VM's public external IP address (look in the Google Cloud Console for the VM), MySQL port number, username, and password. I am assuming that you have not set up SSL on MySQL. If you have problems, edit your question with details on the VM IP address, Firewall rule settings, etc. Mask the IP address so we cannot see it.

Comment: I just saw your update. You have created a VPC firewall rule. Did you attach the rule to the VM? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#rule_assignment

Comment: @JohnHanley, I showed in my edits the output of my VPC rule.  It has the network tagged as "default", which in my case, I believe is the same as my single VM instance, which is part of that network.  The default ingress deny (pri 65536) is still in GCP's default rules, but this priority is higher, so it should take effect.  Is there another step after the VPC creation that needs an explicit "attach"?  The link I read, but there wasn't anything that explicitly described an attachment.

Comment: @JohnHanley, also, when I try from my windows laptop to telnet to the IP:3306, I am connecting in, at least partially.  see edits.

Comment: Google Cloud Console -> VPC Network -> Firewall. Click on the firewall rule under Name. Scroll the page to the bottom. Look for "Applicable to instances". You should see your VM there if the rule is applied correctly.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes it is applied.  updated in the original post.

Comment: well I'm trying to credit John for the answer, but he only commented on my post...please post an "answer" and I can credit you sir.  After making a new instance and walking all the usual steps, I've come to the conclusion I have some setting hiding somewhere making my life hell...the new instance works fine.  thanks for all the guidance @JohnHanley!!!!

Comment: Although I know the steps to guide you to solve the problem, I did not know the exact answer. My suggestion is that you post a detailed answer and I will vote for you. Problems like yours will help others understand how to "problem solve" and better understand the tecchnology.

Comment: @JohnHanley, posted as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @JohnHanley here is a summary of my issues and steps:

1. Get a working setup of mysql workbench with a local pc database.  This ensures you have the DB, and the connection to a local machine working correctly.
2. export the database to a remote system, in my case it was GCE linux VM (ubuntu I used)  There are many easy steps to follow on exporting the db (mysqldump based)
3. ensure linux vm has mysql server and client setup, and import the db
4. now to setup the ssh connection:
5. ensure the port 3306 is open on the linux vm, by going to the VPC service for your vm/project, and insuring the port is open, or adding a rule to expose port 3306 ingress.
6. connect to the vm (you should have already done this before step 3), by using the GCE console and connecting to the instance.  This also ensures you have the local files on the pc for ssh created.  (~/.ssh/google_compute_*)
7. connect to the VM from your pc.  use gcloud console tools to check the next step.  if you haven't been using gcloud console tools yet, get them installed open a command / powershell window.
8. type "gcloud compute ssh "name of instance".  if this connects, you now know you have the server properly configured for ssh, and accept external requests.
9. then setting up mysql workbench is same setup of gcloud ssh request...it can use the same credentials and script, which the helper files exist in the above /.ssh/ folder I referenced.

Answer (score 1):

if you can connect via ssh.

change the connection method
[image]

There you can enter the same data as in your previous ssh connction

[image]